# Getting duplicates through pubsub streaming

Tags: duplicates, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

Source team is saying that they are not sending the duplicates, I am not sure where they are coming from. I am looking for a solution which can actually deduplicates the messages. Please help me.

I have tried the deduplication after loading the data into table but that is not the requirement, we should not load the duplicates itself. Means we need to remove the duplicates from the messages if there are any before loading into the table.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Pub/Sub offers at-least-once delivery guarantees. That means messages can be redelivered. There are typically three situations in which messages get delivered more than once:

1. Duplication is on the publish side. This would be indicated by the same message being delivered with different message IDs.
2. Your processing of a message does not complete before the acknowledgement deadline expires. You could look at the [`subscription/expired_ack_deadlines_count` metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub) to see if this is happening. If it is, then you need to extend your ack deadline or ensure you are processing messages before the deadline expires.
3. Redeliveries due to Pub/Sub's at-least-once delivery guarantee. Even acking messages within the deadline can result in some duplicates, though the rate should be pretty low (typically ~0.1%). You can use [exactly once delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery) to determine when duplicates occur and handle them accordingly.

If you need full depduping, the [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) is the right solution. You can explore the [different deduping options](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/handling-duplicate-data-in-streaming-pipeline-using-pubsub-dataflow).

Comment: Just want to highlight that apparently, Dataflow is being used here (based on tags). Dataflow is still bound to Pub/Sub at-least-once guarantees, but it should ACK the Pub/Sub messages after the first fused stage. Take a look at #3 on the [blog post mentioned by Kamal](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/handling-duplicate-data-in-streaming-pipeline-using-pubsub-dataflow) as it may be helpful.